# Trap and exit big shell script with background processes

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I have 2 shell scripts that contain ffmpeg commands (command1.sh and command2.sh). command2.sh has like 500 ffmpeg commands that trigger one after another with ';', while command1.sh handles audio ffmpeg commands.

**The main issue:** It takes too much to kill the whole script and it takes away for 1-2 minutes the CPU power i need for another executing script so I'm losing CPU power for nothing, because i cannot kill it instantly.

**Code:**
I have **init.sh** that contains :

```
trap 'print TERM received;exit' 15
chmod +x command1.sh;
chmod +x command2.sh;
./command1.sh & ./command2.sh
```

so it triggers both in background.

Then i execute **pkill init.sh** and i catch on the shell **trap** and **exit** the shell script but i get exitCode: 1, failed: true and the commands in the background still execute for 1 min until they get killed by another kill ${pid} which i execute after pkill.

Comment: Your script does not seem to "trigger both in background". It looks like the first is in the background, while the second is in the foreground.  If that's the case, signals will not be acted on until the second exits.  Try `./command1.sh & ./command2.sh & wait`

Comment: Added 'wait', still getting exitCode=1 and it doesn't kill it instantly.

Comment: I do not see `exitCode` anywhere in your code.  You need to show complete code if you expect complete answers.  Your trap will also need to pass a signal along to the children, and they need to respond promptly to the signal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) kill parallelized subtasks

### Some remarks:

- `chmod +x` is useless here. At all you could run `sh command1.sh &` instead.
- You have to kill all subtasks independantly
- As this question is tagged [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), my answer don't use *bashisms*. All script here is tested under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash),  [dash](/questions/tagged/dash) and [busybox](/questions/tagged/busybox).

Something like:

```
#!/bin/sh

for cmd in ./command1.sh ./command2.sh;do
    exec $cmd &
    PIDS="$PIDS $!"
done

trap "kill $PIDS;exit" 15
wait
```

Of coure, between `for cmd in` and `;do`, you could put as many `commandXX.sh` you want (as long you keep line length into maximum supported by your installed OS)

#### Test script:

Here is a quick [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) test script that sleep randomly between 2.0 to 12.99 seconds, then print **`done.`** before exit:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i toSleep
case $1 in '' | *[!0-9]* ) toSleep='RANDOM%10+2' ;; * ) toSleep=$1 ;; esac

exec {dummy}<> <(:)
read -t $toSleep.$RANDOM -u $dummy _
echo done.
```

I've saved this into `command1.sh`, `chmod +x ..` and linked to `command2.sh`...

#### More portable wrapper:

```
#!/bin/sh

for cmd in "$@";do
    exec $cmd &
    PIDS="$PIDS $!"
done

printf "You have to: kill -TERM %d\nto end %d tasks: %s\n" \
    $$ $(echo $PIDS|wc -w) "$PIDS"

trap "kill $PIDS;echo 'Process $$ killed.';exit" 15
wait

echo "Process $$ running $@ ended normally"
```

You could save this [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) script into a file named `simpleParallel.sh`, for sample, then:

```
chmod +x simpleParallel.sh

./simpleParallel.sh ./command1.sh ./command2.sh 
You have to: kill -TERM 741297
to end 2 tasks:  741298 741299
```

Then if you `kill -TERM 741297` from elsewhere,

```
Process 741297 killed.
```

But if you don't, you may read something like:

```
./simpleParallel.sh ./command1.sh ./command2.sh 
You have to: kill -TERM 741968
to end 2 tasks:  741969 741970
done.
done.
Process 741968 running ./command1.sh ./command2.sh ended normally
```

Nota: If you send your kill command while one process is already done, you may see error message like:

```
./simpleParallel.sh: 1: kill: No such process
```

See [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) version could avoid this bug.

#### Following this from another *terminal console*

Before running `./simpleParallel.sh`, you could run `tty` without argument:

```
tty
/dev/pts/2
```

Then in a new free window, you could run:

```
watch ps --tty pts/2
```

while using another window again to run `kill` command.

### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) with some *bashisms*, now:

Under recent bash, there are lot of special feature.

- You could use Array to store backgrounded tasks's PIDs.
- From version 5.0, There is an `$EPOCHREALTIME` variable, which expands to the time in seconds since the Unix epoch with microsecond granularity.
- From version 5.0, Associative arrays allow subscripts containing whitespace.
- From version 5.1, `wait` has a new `[-p VARNAME]` option, which stores the *`PID`* returned by `wait -n` or `wait` without arguments.

My script could become:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A PIDS ENDED
started=$EPOCHREALTIME
for cmd; do
    exec "$cmd" &
    PIDS["$cmd"]=$!
    CMDS[$!]="$cmd"
done
printf "You have to: kill -TERM %d\nto end %d tasks: %s\n" \
    $$ ${#PIDS[@]} "${PIDS[*]}"

trapExit(){
    kill "${PIDS[@]}"
    printf 'Process %s + %d task killed: %s\n' $$ ${#PIDS[@]} "${!PIDS[*]}"
    showDone
    exit 1
}
trap trapExit 15
showDone() {
    for cmd in "${!ENDED[@]}";do
        read -r elap < <(bc -l <<<"${ENDED["$cmd"]}-$started")
        printf "Elapsed: %.4f sec for %s\n" "$elap" "$cmd"
    done
}
while ((${#PIDS[@]}));do  if wait -n -p pid ;then
        printf "Process %d done (%s).\n" "$pid" "${CMDS[pid]}"
        ENDED["${CMDS[pid]}"]=$EPOCHREALTIME
        unset PIDS["${CMDS[pid]}"] CMDS[pid]
fi; done
echo "Process $$ running $* ended normally"
showDone
```

Output could look like:

```
./simpleParallel.bash ./command{1,2}.sh
You have to: kill -TERM 1309816
to end 2 tasks: 1309817 1309818
done.
Process 1309817 done (./command1.sh).
done.
Process 1309818 done (./command2.sh).
Process 1309816 running ./command1.sh ./command2.sh ended normally
Elapsed: 3.1644 sec for ./command1.sh
Elapsed: 4.2488 sec for ./command2.sh
```

or

```
./simpleParallel.bash ./command{1,2}.sh
You have to: kill -TERM 1310031
to end 2 tasks: 1310032 1310033
done.
Process 1310033 done (./command2.sh).
done.
Process 1310032 done (./command1.sh).
Process 1310031 running ./command1.sh ./command2.sh ended normally
Elapsed: 9.1868 sec for ./command1.sh
Elapsed: 3.2310 sec for ./command2.sh
```

If you `kill` them early:

```
./simpleParallel.bash ./command{1,2}.sh
You have to: kill -TERM 1294577
to end 2 tasks: 1294578 1294579
Process 1294577 + 2 task killed: ./command1.sh ./command2.sh
```

If you `kill` them later:

```
./simpleParallel.bash ./command{1,2}.sh
You have to: kill -TERM 1294958
to end 2 tasks: 1294959 1294960
done.
Process 1294959 done (./command1.sh).
Process 1294958 + 1 task killed: ./command2.sh
Elapsed: 3.1779 sec for ./command1.sh
```

or

```
./simpleParallel.bash ./command{1,2}.sh
You have to: kill -TERM 1294971
to end 2 tasks: 1294972 1294973
done.
Process 1294973 done (./command2.sh).
Process 1294971 + 1 task killed: ./command1.sh
Elapsed: 6.9344 sec for ./command2.sh
```

and no error message about trying to kill unexistant pid.

Comment: @Trofin Sorry for late answer...

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I've used trap and i fixed it just as you showed in this comment.

Comment: @Trofin Here is a new [tag:bash] version, with more *features*.